# vbscript accessing Sharepoint 2010 forms to enter data gathered

Tags: sharepoint, vbscript, sharepoint-2010

Our departments are switching from SharePoint 2007 to 2010. The old SharePoints allowed us to use the same URL and Window title for forms, but SharePoint 2010 show the URL and Window title for a list of forms that have been filled out. On that page, there is a link called "Add new item":

[image]

To get to a new form, they have to click that link; which brings up a new window with its own title:

[image]

Here's the code I have to get to the first image:

```
URL = "http://myURL.com/AllItems.aspx"
Window = " - All Tasks"
URLFound = False

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows

For Each objIE In objShell.Windows
Next

For i = 0 to objShellWindows.Count - 1
  Set objIE = objShellWindows.Item(i)
  On Error Resume Next
  If InStr(UCase(objShellWindows.Item(i).LocationURL), UCase(URL)) Then
    If InStr(UCase(objShellWindwos.Item(i).FullName), "IEXPLORE.EXE") Then
      If Err.Number = 0 Then
        If InStr(objShellWindows.Item(i).Document.Title, (Window)) Then
          URLFound = True
          Exit For
        End If
      End If
    End If
  End If
Next

objIE.Visible = True

objIE.Document.All.Item("idAddNewItemLink").Click

Set objShell = Nothing
Set objShellWindows = Nothing
Set objIE = Nothing
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to set the focus for the second image titled " - New Item"? I've tried:

```
Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WShell.AppActivate " - New Item"

Set WShell = Nothing
```

That doesn't work.  I've tried:

```
Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

If objIE.Document.Title = " - All Tasks" Then
  WShell.AppActivate " - New Item"
End If

Set WShell = Nothing
```

That doesn't work either.  Hopefully someone has a solution I can try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 uses Javascript to open a list form in a modal dialog.  The actual form would be in page called newform.aspx.  For example, if your list is at http://mysite.mydomain.com/lists/tasks, the new item page would be at http://mysite.mydomain.com/lists/tasks/newform.aspx.

Perhaps an easier way to d this is to use the Javascript Object Model.  Microsoft includes a function called `showModalDialog` that would open the dialog window for you.

```
function openNew() {
  var options = {
    title: "New Item",
    url: "/path/to/your/list/NewForm.aspx"
  };

  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog( options );
}
```

Then in the ribbon add

```
<a onclick="openNew();return false;" href="#">Add New</a>
```

You can also make it more generic bu passing the url to the openNew function

```
function openNew(url) {
  var options = {
    url: url,
    title: "New Item"
  }
  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog( options );
}
```

Add New

Comment: So I would have to copy the first part of my code that got me to the list and call the URL and Window title of the form?

Comment: If I understand what you're doing, then yes.

Comment: I'm getting to `If InStr(UCase(objShellWindows.Item(i).LocationURL), UCase(URL)) Then` and then the program stops. I copied and pasted everything I have above, except I changed the URL and Window, and it just stops. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't quite understand why you're doing it this way.  Why not just use `showModalDialog` to open the dialog?

Comment: Is this something that can run with VBScript? The code at the top of the page was something that one of our other developers came up with and it's worked up until this point where I need to gain a new URL and Window title.

Comment: The showModalDialog function is a JavaScript function. Take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: I guess my issue is a little more complex. I don't have access to the SharePoint coding, so I can't add the `onclick` to the ribbon. My program is an external program developed in Macro Express Pro using VBScript to do all the behind the scenes actions. If `showModalDialog` was part of the Document Object Model, then I could use it. I'm gathering data from IBM Personal Communications emulators, then entering it in SharePoint.

Comment: Do you have the ability to add a content editor Web part to the page and the ability to add a Javascript file to a document library? If you do, you can use this. If you're sticking with vbscript, then I don't know how else to help you.

Comment: I misunderstood at first what you were saying, but when I changed the URL to NewForm.aspx instead of AllItems.aspx, I was able to open the form directly and print all the data like I did in the old SharePoint. @Robbert, thank you for your advice and patience.